# Что такое ToDo,ToDo-list,ToDo-Приложение

Tags: терминология

На просторах интернета встретил такое выражение ToDo, ToDo-list, ToDo-приложение, но нигде не сказано что это такое. Это одно и тоже, если нет, то чем оно отличается?

Comment: Список запланированных дел, которые нужно сделать.

Comment: Приложение в данном случае это простойший пример как с "Hello World". Оно может добавлять в список дела, а затем отмечать их как выполненные.

Comment: Помню был сайт с коллекцией тудушек на разных языках, но найти не могу. Никто не подскажет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это простой список задач. Нужен он для того чтобы контролировать и не забывать дела, которые нужно сделать за день. А `Todo` может интерпретироваться по разному, но означает одно и тоже, это список дел/задач.

Вот пример приложения `Todoist`. Очень удобный и простой в использовании.
[image: example]